# Jenkins should ask password while build

Tags: jenkins-plugins

How jenkins should ask password while build a job in jenkins,please give me details step by step.I created a user in jenkins, I wants when I will build any job in jenkins it should ask my login password.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want your build to use that password? or impersonate to that user while it runs the build? or just use the password as a property to update any configuration file?

Comment: Thanks Curious for your response ... Actually I am trying to achieving while I am login to jenkins with my credentials with username and password , thenI have created a job in jenkins. when I am trying to BUILD that job then it should ask me password. After giving password I can see my BUILD is success or fail.